# How to plot weekly values ​on a time series graph of daily values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
          DATE   WEEK  ANOM_TMAX  ANOM_TMIN
0   2022-01-03      1  -0.977143      -1.89
1   2022-01-04      1  -0.977143      -1.89
2   2022-01-05      1  -0.977143      -1.89
3   2022-01-06      1  -0.977143      -1.89
4   2022-01-07      1  -0.977143      -1.89
..         ...    ...        ...        ...
352 2022-12-21     51  -0.508571      -2.38
353 2022-12-22     51  -0.508571      -2.38
354 2022-12-23     51  -0.508571      -2.38
355 2022-12-24     51  -0.508571      -2.38
356 2022-12-25     51  -0.508571      -2.38

[357 rows x 4 columns]
```

I want to plot spans from the  dataframe indices (or the DATE column) to delimit the seasons (summer, fall, winter, and spring). This only for the spans. But then I want to plot the time series plot based on the weeks (week column) and the ANOM_TMAX and ANOM_TMIN columns. That's why I made this code:

```
df['WEEK']=df['WEEK'].astype(int).astype(str)

index_fall = df.index[78]
index_winter = df.index[170]
index_spring = df.index[264]
index_summer = df.index[353]


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(20, 15))

ax1.axvspan(index_fall, index_winter, color='silver', label='fall', alpha=0.5)
ax1.axvspan(index_winter, index_spring, color='navy', label='winter', alpha=0.5)
ax1.axvspan(index_spring, index_summer, color='gold', label='spring', alpha=0.5)
ax1.axvspan(index_summer, df.index[-1], color='darkred', label='summer', alpha=0.5)
ax1.axvspan(datos.index[0], index_fall, color='darkred', label='summer', alpha=0.5)

ax2.axvspan(index_fall, index_winter, color='silver', label='fall', alpha=0.5)
ax2.axvspan(index_winter, index_spring, color='navy', label='winter', alpha=0.5)
ax2.axvspan(index_spring, index_summer, color='gold', label='spring', alpha=0.5)
ax2.axvspan(index_summer, df.index[-1], color='darkred', label='summer', alpha=0.5)
ax2.axvspan(datos.index[0], index_fall, color='darkred', label='summer', alpha=0.5)

df.plot('WEEK',["ANOM_TMAX"], alpha=0.9,style='--', color='darkred', marker='D',markersize=6, fontsize = 15.0,linewidth=5,ax=ax1)

df.plot('WEEK',["ANOM_TMIN"], alpha=0.9,style='--',color='navy',marker='D',markersize=6, fontsize = 15.0,linewidth=5,ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that the values of the week are repeated and also those of ANOM_TMAX and ANOM_TMIN. That's why when I plot I get several repeated values (7 for each week) in the time series plot. I would like to leave the spans in the background but plot only the weeks with the values of ANOM_TMAX and ANOM_TMIN (one value per week).

How could I do this?